How to predict whether a redox or an acid-base reaction will occur?
I've been thinking a lot about this question, but even after intense research, I didn't find any satisfying answer, even here. So here's my question, illustrated with an example:
We have a negatively charged Cl- ion which somehow wants to get rid of its negative charge. Now for me there are two primary options:

Redox reaction: The Cl- ions simply oxidate and then react to Cl$_2$.
Acid-base reaction: The other species gives protons to the Cl- Ions, which results in the creation of the acid HCl.

At least for my understanding, a negative charge can be removed by either giving electrons away or simply receiving protons.
How can I tell which reaction happens when?

As in many other sciences and arts, it is not possible in chemistry to make good predictions without knowledge and experience. Like the knowledge you need strong oxidants to oxidize Cl- or that HCl in H2O is practically nonexistent, as HCl is a strong acid.

It is done by chemical analysis. In many cases the analysis has been done and recorded and one can research the process in books, journals, compendia, even Wikipedia and Websites such as this. As indicated above Experience and knowledge can help in an unknown but analysis is necessary.

List the compounds present in solution and check their relative redox potentials and acid dissociation constants.
